# Change PSI or download software to Logitech G900 mouse

Tags: mouse

I have:

Operating System: Kubuntu 19.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.3
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.67.0
Qt Version: 5.12.4
Kernel Version: 5.3.0-53-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 4 × Intel® Pentium® CPU 4415U @ 2.30GHz
Memory: 11,5 GiB of RAM

And a `Logitech G900` which I love dearly. Usually I use it on my gamer PC with Win10. But I would also like to use it on my Kubuntu laptop. The cursor moves very fast. The software has PSI settings to adjust specific speeds. Any help on how to set the PSI speed down will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the pointer speed you can go to

Settings > Input Devices > Mouse > Pointer speed